# Load Configuration from string

Tags: .net, configuration-files

I want to create a [Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx) object from an xml string or stream rather than a file. But as far as I can see, the ConfigurationManager requires a file path to instantiate a Configuration object. Does anyone know a way of creating a Configuration object from something other than a file?

Comment: I wish I knew! I would love to do this myself - but having really found any way - the .NET configuration system is a bit of a locked-down blackbox in that regard, unfortunately - and hasn't changed (for the better) with .NET 4, either :-(

Answer (score 1):

Just save the stream to a file using `System.IO` and load it with

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap(filename))
```

### Documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration(v=VS.90).aspx